# Wicket 6 IColumn How the name can be of type other than string?

Tags: java, wicket

Interface IColumn contains a method getSortProperty(), which returns a value of any type S. How the name can be of type other than string?

```
    /**
     * Returns the name of the property that this header sorts. If null is returned the header will
     * be unsortable.
     * 
     * @return the sort property
     */

S getSortProperty();
```

http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/IColumn.html

In wicket older version 6:

```
PropertyColumn<SomeClass> column = new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Header"), "sortProperty", "propertyExpression");
```

Wicket 6: description:

```
PropertyColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, S sortProperty, String propertyExpression);
```

example:

```
PropertyColumn<SomeClass, Long> column = new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Header"), ?, "propertyExpression");
```

what to write on the ground "?"

Comment: you talk about version 1.4, I'm using 6.3

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when upgrading to Wicket 6.  In one place I overrode a sort method, and was returning column.getSortProperty().  It threw an error due to expecting an object of type Serializable instead of String, which was what I was returning before.... Anyway, I just changed my return type to Serializable and it appears to be working great now!?!  If you want the string you can call column.getSortProperty().toString();  I found a short reference to the change in the repeater section of this link: [Wicket6MigrationGuide](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-60.html)

Comment: I'll try your way later, thanks a lot!

Comment: @OnesAndZeros your link is no more valid, hope you meant this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+6.0 The idea of parameterized sorting is nice, from OOP and generics point of view, but is it also usefull? For example in Oracle DB one can use `order by 2`, that means that it will be sorted by second column, but this is all I can come up. Other ideas are just made up and nothing what PropertyModel cannot solve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example using a `PropertyColumn<SomeClass, Long>` you have to use a `Long` value as the second parameter, as this is the type of the sort property.

If your sort property is a String, simply use `PropertyColumn<SomeClass, String>` and pass your property to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I used as the second parameter String, and it began to work as previous version.
The issue was caused by the research interests, how can I do if the second type other than String

Answer (score 0):

javadoc at http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/IColumn.html says

```
getSortProperty

java.lang.String getSortProperty()

    Returns the name of the property that this header sorts. If null is returned the header will be unsortable.

    Returns:
        a string representing the sort property
```

Comment: you talk about version 1.5, I'm using 6.3

Comment: In version 6.5.0 JavaDoc is the same, but return type is different - S. If it has to be name I'd expect String.