# Wicket 6 IColumn How the name can be of type other than string?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

This question was already asked ([Wicket 6 IColumn How the name can be of type other than string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864075/wicket-6-icolumn-how-the-name-can-be-of-type-other-than-string)), but it was not answered. I highlighted the questions to answer bold...

Interface IColumn contains a method getSortProperty(), which returns a value of any type S. **How the name can be of type other than string?**

```
    /**
     * Returns the name of the property that this header sorts. If null is returned the header will
     * be unsortable.
     * 
     * @return the sort property
     */

S getSortProperty();
```

http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/IColumn.html

In wicket older version 6:

```
PropertyColumn<SomeClass> column = new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Header"), "sortProperty", "propertyExpression");
```

Wicket 6: description:

```
PropertyColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, S sortProperty, String propertyExpression);
```

example:

```
PropertyColumn<SomeClass, Long> column = new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Header"), ?, "propertyExpression");
```

**what to write on the ground "?"**

Answer (score 0):

```
PropertyColumn<SomeClass, Long> column = new PropertyColumn(Model.of("Header"), 4l, "propertyExpression");
```

E.g. this could be used if SortableDataProvider was able to identify the sorted column by index (here 4th).

Answer (score 0):

sortProperty is a String identifying a property to sort on. As such it will always be a String.

For instance, if your table is on a collections of MyFirstSortableClass, which contains a 'date' property (of type 'Date' with corresponding getters/setters) you would make "date" the sortProperty so the SortableDataProvider chosen for the table knows to use the 'date' property of MyFirstSortableClass to sort the list.

How the dataprovider sorts is up to it's implementation, for example in our project we have both dataproviders which sort in the database via an order by-clause and dataproviders which sort in java via a List.sort or something similar.